# Closing zygote and seeing simple interface

Tags: terminal

Can i'm close zygote on my phone and see "terminal"? If i'm closing zygote with

```
killall zygote
```

my phone just rebooted and graphics interface starts again.

Comment: First you need to enable virtual terminals and kernel console in kernel configuration. Then modify `init` services to run `getty` and `login` on terminal instead of starting SurfaceFlinger and `zygote` GUI components.

Answer (score 1):

> Can i'm close zygote on my phone and see "terminal"?

No. Android is not like a GNU/Linux desktop, with TTYs open in the background behind X Windows. Killing `zygote` is not like killing X Windows, it's like killing `init`. There isn't a TTY behind it you can log into.

Comment: It's not like killing init because init in Android still work.